# Is asking if someone is a part of the LGBTQ community illegal if done so for statistical purposes?

Tags: united-states, applications

Yesterday I was filling out an application, and in with the EEOC information, the application asked me if I was a part of the LGBTQ community. Irrespective of whether I am or not (or decline to answer), is asking such a personal question of a candidate legal? Also, for what purposes could they be collecting that data if not a strictly EEOC type of a thing? This is for a job in Illinois.

Comment: Surely this depends on the jurisdiction

Comment: What state are you in? And before you start getting close votes for this being a legal question, I believe this falls under the realm of legal questions that most HR professionals should know the answer to. See the [meta discussion](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1861/16983).

Comment: @DavidK It was for a job in Illinois

Comment: How are they defining "part of the community"? What if you're not LGBTQ but go to rallies, participate in pro-LGBTQ activism, etc.? Seems like a shifty way to ask what they *really* want to know.

Comment: They ask so that they can prove they are hiring LGBT people.  I've also been asked if I have any disabilities

Comment: @RichardU The problem I see with them asking such questions is what if a person IS, say they are for statistical reasons, and it somehow gets out and causes the person trouble. So it's not only a legal thing, but a moral one as well of "outing" a person

Comment: In my experience, such questions that might cross a line when for asking statistical purposes usually have a check for "Prefer not to Answer". If it's there, check that.  Having said that, we can't answer legal questions here and voting to close.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/18255/16983) useful. Basically it's just statistical to report to the government an overall view of the applicant pool.

Comment: @JesseCohoon Personally, I leave those questions blank.  The last time I said "yes" to the disability question, I was targeted for my disabilities.  Never again.

Comment: @RichardU being targeted (and hired!) for ANYTHING would be preferable than struggling to get by... That's the problem of having some experience in a variety of fields instead of a lot in one or 2.

Comment: @JesseCohoon First off, the day I allow myself to be hired out of pity is the day I end it all. Secondly, what  I mean by "targeted", I mean I, and everyone else in a now (rightfully) bankrupt company who let HR know that they had disabilities were let go during a mass layoff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a [majority of states](https://www.fastcompany.com/3057357/the-future-of-work/heres-everywhere-in-america-you-can-still-get-fired-for-being-lgbt), it's entirely legal to *fire* someone for being gay or trans, to say nothing of asking. It's also generally legal to *ask* anything, but is typically prohibited by company policy because actually acting on that information could be illegal.

This will be different internationally, but you say "EEOC", so you're presumably in the US.

Comment: You're right it is for a job in the US, but this is the VERY first time I came across an organization asking this question, and was taken aback!

Comment: In the majority of states, it's legal to fire you if your socks are untied.

Comment: @RichardU socks untied...?

Comment: @JesseCohoon he's referring to at-will employment which exists in one form or another in most states (there are exceptions in many states though). At-will means you can be fired for any reason or no reason. There are exceptions however such as discrimination. You can't fire someone because of their race, gender, etc. It's the exceptions that vary among at-will states.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep - You can still be fired for a discriminatory reason.  No one goes to jail for it, and you probably wont get your job back.  But the company could be forced to pay a civil penalty for such an action.

Comment: @Chad correct, but companies are getting smart.  They'll wait until there is a RIF, and bury your layoff in the rest.  Also, company policies are now written to be so clandestine that you are always in violation of one or another at any given time.  A common one is to have so many procedures in place that you cannot possibly follow them all and still be productive.  Follow the procedures, get fired for low productivity, be productive, get fired for violating procedures

Comment: @RichardU - Most companies have learned that it doesnt matter what your sexuality or gender identity is if you are productive and dont cause problems they keep you around, and if you arent...

Comment: Geez, @Chad . I didn't say you were unable to fire someone, I said "can't"  by which I was implying "legally". The underlying implication then is there could be consequences for the company such as the civil penalty you mentioned, but there could actually be criminal penalties if there's a pattern or actually discriminatory practice. That's Federal, states may have additional penalties.

Comment: @Chad.  Often, but not always the case.  I got swept out along with everyone else with a disability because there were a few idiots who were filing ADA action after ADA action for things as ludicrous as the color of cells in an excel spreadsheet.  Yes, you read that right.  When a company has had enough, they'll find a reason to get rid of anyone in the "protected group" when they're getting problems from that group.