# In a job application, can someone self-identify as an ethnicity that they do not belong to?

Tags: job-search, united-states

Just an assumption. Let's say John belongs to the Asian or Caucasian variety, and he wants to obtain a position in the software engineer field in the US. Can he self-identify as Hispanic, African American or just other? And is it harmful to reject answering that question?

And in general, what is the purpose of that question in the job application?

Comment: Related: [EEO Self-Identification Form: Should I fill out diversity information?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18236/eeo-self-identification-form-should-i-fill-out-diversity-information)

Comment: @RichardU should such a woman identify herself as Hispanic? Would that give her an advantage in the selection process?

Comment: @DylanChensky minority set-asides and upwardly adjusted scoring for hiring purposes

Comment: Self-identity is a tricky thing - it is definitely important that people of various genders, orientations, races, or cultures should be able to be comfortable asserting their identity - but sometimes, it can go [too far](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=wigger&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiolbyarLbSAhVIF5QKHXA2BfwQ_AUICCgB&biw=1680&bih=935)

Comment: @RichardU - Not sure what your source is, but that's quite wrong:   http://pewrsr.ch/1dct41x   Anyone who is descended from a Spanish speaking culture, including their once-conquered territories, can be considered Hispanic.  E.G. Cameron Diaz.  Brazille is excluded in your list because it was a Portuguese territory, at one point.  FYI - I'm married into a Hispanic family.  They're VERY up-to-speed on this issue.

Comment: I put *"Klingon Elf"* in these surveys ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you work, this could be considered fraud and therefore might make you liable in a lawsuit by the hiring company if they found out after hiring you. I Am Not A Lawyer; please consult one before taking any action like this (or just play it safe).

In any case, it is a very bad idea to lie on your application, and I would wager that most employers would immediately trash your application for such an obvious lie, it damages your reputation too much in their first impression. It's not smart.

Employers usually use these question to track internal diversity in order to make sure they aren't unfairly hiring (and possibly setting themselves up for a lawsuit).

Comment: @DylanChensky I don't think that's relevant, can you explain why you think it is? Hiring diversity quotas aren't required by law, but lots of companies still have them to mitigate the risk of being found guilty of discrimination.

Comment: And companies need this information so they can say "we increased the number of xxx employees by one percent".